# How do I access the datasource of a detailsview in the databound event since DataItem is always null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-detail, detailsview

I am converting a single GridView to a master/detailsview as the number of GV columns is spanning more than 2 screens. I have some controls that I dynamically show/hide in the Gridview and I have hit a wall replicating the behavior in the DetailsView.

In my gridView_RowDatabound event I would do something like:

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {            
        DbDataRecord record = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Row.DataItem;
        bool flagW = (bool)record.GetValue(17);
        bool flagD = (bool)record.GetValue(18);
        int Consumption = (int)record.GetValue(21); 
        if (flagW == false)
        {
            WButton.Visible = true;
            WFlag.Visible = false;                
        }
        else
        {
            WButton.Visible = false;
            WFlag.Visible = true;
            WFlag.Checked = true;
            bool WarComplete = CheckWarrantyCompleted("WarrantyPart", record.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

So, what I am doing is accessing fields from the SQLDataSource that are not bound to the GV's controls.
The issue I run into is If I do a similar thing in the DetailsView_DataBound event, the DataItem is null. The DV only has data to bind on PostBack since it is populated on the GridView_SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem;
    DetailsView view = (DetailsView)sender;
    DetailsViewRowCollection rows = view.Rows;
    CheckBox WFlag = (CheckBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("WFlag");
    Button WButton = (Button)DetailsView1.FindControl("WButton");
    CheckBox DFlag = (CheckBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("DFlag");
    Button DButton = (Button)DetailsView1.FindControl("DButton");

    if (DetailsView1.DataItem != null)
    {
        DbDataRecord record = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)DetailsView1.DataItem;
        bool flagW = (bool)row[17];
        bool flagD = (bool)row[18];
        int Consumption = (int)row[21];

        if (flagW == false)
        {
            WButton.Visible = true;
            WFlag.Visible = false;
        }    
    }  
}
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
              runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              DataKeyNames="RequestNumber"
              AllowSorting="True"
              Width="450px"
              BackColor="White"
              BorderColor="#999999"
              BorderStyle="None"
              BorderWidth="1px"
              CellPadding="3"
              GridLines="Vertical"
              HorizontalAlign="Justify"                                        
              OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging"
              EnableModelValidation="True">
<asp:DetailsView
              ID="DetailsView1"
              runat="server"                        
              Height="50px"
              Width="485px"
              CellPadding="3"
              AutoGenerateRows="False"
              DatasourceID="SqlDataSource2"
              ForeColor="White"
              EnableModelValidation="True"
              DataKeyNames="RequestNumber"
              HorizontalAlign="Left"
              Style="margin-right: 0px"
              OnItemCommand="DetailsView1_ItemCommand" 
              OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound"  
              defaultmode="Edit"                       
              >
                    <Fields...</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Process_PartRequests WHERE (Process_PartRequests.RequestNumber = @RequestNumber)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="RequestNumber" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm thinking that there is no way to get to the original datasource. So now I am wondering if my only option is to grab the Bound ID in rows[0].Cells[1] and create a new DbDataRecord and perform my logic against that. It seems like a long way to go for something that should be visible through the control itself.

Is this really the only option I'm left with?

Comment: I don't underatand it. _"The DV only has data on PostBack since it is populated on the GridView_SelectedIndexChanged event"_ If you assign the `DataSource` there and call `DetailsView1.DataBind()` then `DataItem` is not null. Are you in insert-mode? Then it would be null.

Comment: How are you attaching the DataBound event handler?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  I'm not doing an explicit databind. The DV is tied to the GV via a Control Parameter in the DV's DataSource. I'll add the DV and DataSource above...

Comment: @Malk I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Stupid mistake! I had OnDataBinding="DetailsView1_DataBound" set instead of OnDataBound when I was working on another issue.